# Return a Function within a Function

Tags: javascript

Here is an example of code I am experimenting with:

```
var hello = function hi(){
    function bye(){
        console.log(hi);
        return hi;
    }
    bye();
};

hello();
```

Here is a [repl.it](http://repl.it/Vvx) link

I am trying to return the function `hi` from my function `bye`.  As you can see, when I `console.log(hi)` the value appears to present, but my return statement doesn't return the hi function. Why isn't the `return` statement returning the reference to `hi`?

Comment: `return bye();`

Comment: bye() returns hi() does it make any sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't make think complicated by defining a function inside another one

Define your `hi` function first like this for example

```
function hi (message) 
{ 
     console.log(message) 
}
```

it takes an argument and show it on the console

now let's define our `bye` function

```
function bye ()
{
     hi(" Called from the function bye ");
}
```

no when you call `bye`, you call `hi` at the same time

```
bye(); // it will show on the console the message " Called from ... "
```

If you want to return a function from a function it's easy you define your `hi` function like this

```
function hi (message) 
{ 
     console.log(message) 
}
```

and the `bye` function returns the `hi` function like this

```
function bye() 
{
     return hi;
}
```

All you need to do now, is to call the `bye` function and give the argument to show in the console to what was returned , just like this

```
bye()(" This is a sample message ");
```

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to `return` bye.

```
return bye();
```